# keyed particles wont render at all

Tags: particles

i am using 2.81. i have two base objects and the particals(not halo) are morphing from one to another pretty smoothly, but while rendering the keyed particles wont render at all, and it just looks very unpleasant.[image: keyed particles are highlighted in orange]

Comment: can you try to be more clear? your problem isn't clear by the question.
Press the edit button and change it

Comment: you see the highlighted particles in orange are not being rendered in cycles, they are keyed particles

Comment: oh ok thanks i'll see what i find

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T69238 it seems to be a bug

Comment: oh no :( let me see whats 2.82 has to offer